# UseEffect to redirect causes flicker and component navigation away from to render in React typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `useEffect` to navigate away from a page and to another based on a certain condition. However, when I do this, and the condition to redirect is present, page flashes briefly before redirecting.

```
import authService from "../src/services/authService";

function App() {
  const [currentUserStatus, setCurrentUserStatus] = React.useState(
    authService.getCurrentUser()
  );

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUserStatus == null) {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

With the above example, if `currentUserStatus` is null and the page navigates to `'/login'`, it will flash the `<h1>Test</h1>` before redirecting. It's only a fraction of a second but it still occurs and is quite obvious.

How can I prevent this or find a better way to redirect?

Comment: If you using react-router-dom v6, you can try `Navigate` and redirect to login page if currentUserStatus is null else show the content.  `{currentUserStatus === null ? <Navigate to="/login" /> :  <div>{test}</div>}`

Comment: I think you are also missing the dependency array in useEffect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that useEffect runs **after** the render cycle.  So, if you want to make sure that the `<h1>Test</h1>` content isn't revealed to a user who isn't logged into your site, make sure that you use conditional rendering as well:

```
function App() {
  const [currentUserStatus, setCurrentUserStatus] = React.useState(
    authService.getCurrentUser()
  );

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUserStatus == null) {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  });

  if (!currentUserStatus) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```